# Jquery replaceWith keep onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I keep `onclick=""` value with JQuery replaceWith ? I'm making a assets system that preload every image and put it on a Javascript `image()` object, and using a special data attribute for img urls

```
<img data-assets="images/test.png" onclick="alert('test')">
```

**turn into :** (using jquery replaceWith)

```
<img src="assets/images/test.png">
```

**What I want:**

```
<img src="assets/images/test.png" onclick="alert('test')">
```

**My code:**

```
$("[data-assets]").each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith(Game.Preloading.Assets.Images[$(this).data('assets')]);
});
```

How can I fix that ? Thanks

Comment: Why not assign the onclick programmatically so that you don't have to worry about messing with html attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While iterating over each `[data-assets]` element, you could set the corresponding `onclick` attribute before replacing the element:

```
$("[data-assets]").each(function() {
  var $newImg = $(Game.Preloading.Assets.Images[$(this).data('assets')]);
  $newImg.attr('onclick', $(this).attr('onclick'));

  $(this).replaceWith($newImg);
});
```

However, it would be better to just add a `src` attribute on the existing element rather than replacing it:

```
$("[data-assets]").each(function() {
  this.src = $(Game.Preloading.Assets.Images[$(this).data('assets')]).attr('src');
});
```

Ideally, you *should* be using [unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and avoiding the inline JavaScript event listeners, but both of the above snippets should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better off to simple query for your attribute, then use the each method to update the SRC attribute on each matched element.

Im on my phone so a more detailed answer is difficult...

But here goes

```
$("[data-assets]").each(function(){ $(this).attr("src", Game.Preloading.Assets.Images[$(this).data('assets')]); });
```

Comment: If I change the src, will the image be reloaded or it will be like if I made replaceWith?

Comment: Yes I know but I'm asking if it will be loaded another time or it will take from the image() object ?

Comment: If it is in browser cache it will not be reloaded